# How to Mount Secure HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, fuse

To let the standard file system user or a program see the HDFS name space as a locally mounted directory, CDH4 i.e. has a [hadoop-hdfs-fuse](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Mountable+HDFS) component.

It is working with **NON** secure HDFS, but on a Kerberos secured HDFS, how to do it there?

Thks.

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos authentication support for fuse_dfs executable (shipped with Hadoop distribution) has been added since version 2.0.2 of Apache Hadoop distribution.

I have spent a lot of time on figuring out how this should be configured.I have found that **In order to make Fuse-DFS pick the correct configuration files(that contain authentication type, kerberos not simple etc...), `CLASSPATH` must contain `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` before Hadoop jar directories**.

When using Kerberos authentication, users must run kinit before accessing the FUSE mount point. Failing to do this will result in I/O errors when users attempt to access the mount point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use py-hdfs-mount which supports Kerberos and is easier to setup: https://github.com/EDS-APHP/py-hdfs-mount

Answer (score 0):

The hdfs fuse module does not have kerberos support yet.